# Casting a specific element of an array - java

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I have an array as:

`String letters [] = {a, b, c, d, e};`

Can I cast a specific element let's say "a" ? I want to get its ascii value, so I did this but it is not working:

```
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    Integer iDecimal = (int) a[0];    // the a[0] is wrong!!

    System.out.print(iDecimal);
}
```

Any ideas about how to cast in such cases?

Comment: Pseudo-code isn't very helpful. I have no idea if your issues are with syntax errors as what you are showing here would not compile.

Comment: You can't cast a string to `int`. Either change the type of your array to `char` or get the first character of the strings via `charAt(0)` and then either cast to int or box to `Character` and get the code point of that character (needed for unicode).

Comment: I think when you say "ASCII value," you actually mean [codepoint](http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_point) or [code unit](http://unicode.org/glossary/#code_unit). Using "ASCII" like "[Kleenex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark)" is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast a[0] which doesn't exist, to access your array you need to do letters[0] and then try working with it. I suggest changing type of your array to char and then casting it, you can't do that with String.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the array as object array, but be aware that this is bad coding style, since you are mixing different types in one array.

```
Object letters [] = {5, "b", 'c'};
```

The object array contains an integer, a string, and a character you may then iterate over the array and test what object type you have. 
The integer element is autoboxed to an Integer-Object.

But again i would not recommend doing so, since element testing is expensive.

```
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    if (a[i]) instanceof Integer)
      Integer iDecimal = (Integer) a[i];
}
```

Comment: I believe if I use a struct it's gonna be better since i need to use different types.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want just the ASCII code for the first character in each string in your array, then you can can access that char then cast it to an int.

```
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    int iChar = (int) letters[i][0];

    System.out.print(iChar);
}
```

`letters[i]` is the *i*th string in the letters array.

`letters[i][0]` is the first character of the *i*th string in the letters array, and will be of type `char`.

`(int)letters[i][0]` is the integer value equivalent to the first character of the *i*th string in the letters array.

Strictly this will give the first UTF-16 word in the string, but for values <127 it will be the same as the ASCII value.

ints are not decimal values, so don't call them decimals. The BigDecimal type is used for decimal values.